# SQL query to conditionally select a field value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an SQL query that joins 3 tables to return me the required data. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT (s.user_created, 
        u.first_name, 
        u.last_name, 
        u.email, 
        s.school_name, 
        p.plan_name, 
        substring( a.message, 11), u.phone1) 
FROM cb_school s
inner join ugrp_user u 
    on s.user_created = u.user_id 
inner join cb_plan p 
    on s.current_plan = p.plan_id 
inner join audit a 
    on u.user_id = a.user_id
where s.type = 'sample' 
      and a.module_short = 'sample-user' 
      and s.created_time > current_timestamp - interval '10 day';
```

The query works fine if all the attributes are present. Now for few of my rows, the following value would be `a.module_short = 'sample-user'` missing. But since I have included it as an `AND` condition, those rows will not be returned. I am trying to return an empty string for that field if it is present, else the value as per my current query. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: You are not selecting `module_short`, so I have no idea what the empty string is referring to.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, module_short is conditionally checked for its value, so I will miss a row if that row doesn't have the specified module_short value. I need all the remaining data even if the module short value is not the specified one

Comment: Move the "AND a.module_short = 'sample-user'" into the inner join after "ON u.user_id = a.user_id"

Comment: @GeoThomas . . . Then just remove the condition.  Or at least provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Think you could possibly use a CASE WHEN statement, like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.module_short = 'sample-user' THEN a.module_short
       ELSE '' END AS a.module_short
FROM TableA
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `COALESCE` it returns the first not null.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(a.module_short,'')
FROM TableA  AS a
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show all users that have at least one module_short.
If the module_short contains 'sample-user' then it should show it, else it should show NULL as module_short. You only want 1 row per user, even if it has multiple module_shorts.

You can use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql), [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) and the [CASE clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) for this question.

**Example Question**

I have 3 tables.

- Users: Users with an ID
- Modules: Modules with an ID
- UserModules: The link between users and modules. You user can have multiple models.

I need a query that returns me all users that have at least 1 module with 2 columns UserName and ModuleName.
I only one 1 row for each user. The ModuleName should only display SQL if the user has that module. Else it should display no module.

**Example Tables:**

Users:

```
id  name    
1   Manuel  
2   John    
3   Doe
```

Modules:

```
id  module
1   StackOverflow
2   SQL
3   StackExchange
4   SomethingElse
```

UserModules:

```
id  module_id   user_id
1   1           2
2   1           3
4   2           2
5   2           3
6   3           1
7   3           3
8   4           1
9   4           3
```

**Example Query:**

```
with CTE as (
select
    u.name as UserName
    , CASE
        WHEN m.module = 'SQL' THEN 'SQL' ELSE NULL END as ModuleName
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u.id
                                 ORDER BY (CASE
        WHEN m.module = 'SQL' THEN 'Ja' ELSE NULL END) DESC) as rn
from UserModules as um
    inner join Users as u
        on um.user_id = u.id
    inner join Modules as m
        on um.module_id = m.id
        )
select UserName, ModuleName from CTE
where rn = 1
```

**Example Result:**

```
UserName    ModuleName
Manuel      NULL        
John        SQL         
Doe         SQL
```

**Your query would look like this:**

```
with UsersWithRownumbersBasedOnModule_short as (
SELECT s.user_created, 
        u.first_name, 
        u.last_name, 
        u.email, 
        s.school_name, 
        p.plan_name, 
        substring( a.message, 11),
        u.phone1)
        CASE    
            WHEN a.module_short = 'sample-user' 
                THEN a.module_short 
            ELSE NULL 
            END AS ModuleShort
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u.user_id ORDER BY (
            CASE    
                WHEN a.module_short = 'sample-user' 
                    THEN a.module_short 
                ELSE NULL 
            END) DESC) as rn
FROM cb_school s
inner join ugrp_user u 
    on s.user_created = u.user_id 
inner join cb_plan p 
    on s.current_plan = p.plan_id 
inner join audit a 
    on u.user_id = a.user_id
where s.type = 'sample' 
      and s.created_time > current_timestamp - interval '10 day';)
select * from UsersWithRownumbersBasedOnModule_short
where rn = 1
```

*PS: I removed a lose bracket after SELECT and your [SUBSTRING()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) is missing 1 parameter, it needs 3.*

Comment: The case is that I can have multiple values for module_short for the specified user_id, but I want its value only if the module_short  value = 'sample-user'. In All other cases I want to set that field as empty

Comment: I have tried your solution and getting an error as : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 3:         ELSE NULL AS a.message,
                          ^

Comment: My bad, ELSE NULL is unncessary, if you leave the ELSE it will make all NULL that do not match the case.
And you need to end the case with END. I have also removed the first answer since that wasn't your question.

Comment: this approach won't work for me since all the rows will be returned multiple times for all the other values of module_short. I don't want those rows.That is duplicate data for me

Comment: Please provide an example of how the tables look that you are retrieving the data from. Since it determines how to edit the query to not leave data 'behind'. What other fields do you need from the Audit table since you do not select any.

Comment: Please also provide an example what you expect as result.

Comment: I've modified the answer once more with examples and the clauses/functions you could use.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT (s.user_created, 
        u.first_name, 
        u.last_name, 
        u.email, 
        s.school_name, 
        p.plan_name, 
        substring( a.message, 11), u.phone1) 
    FROM cb_school s
    INNER JOIN ugrp_user u 
    ON s.user_created = u.user_id 
    INNER JOIN cb_plan p 
    ON s.current_plan = p.plan_id
    INNER JOIN audit a 
    ON u.user_id = a.user_id
    AND a.module_short = 'sample-user' 
    WHERE s.type = 'sample' 
    AND s.created_time > current_timestamp - interval '10 day';
```